# How to add extra text data to a cell in react-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, react-datepicker

How to add extra text data to a cell in react-datepicker? Like in this picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQxlC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this can be achieved with the `renderDayContents` option https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-custom-day